# SSL redirect for dynamic URL

Tags: .htaccess

I'm flabbergasted! I've been trying for hours to redirect, via .htaccess, two specific pages to HTTPS, and force all other pages to always use HTTP. One of the URLs is dynamic, and that's where my problem lies. No example I've found has worked for me. Below is my present code. I finally did get the turning on part to work, so it's just turning off SSL I need help with. The only pages that should use SSL are `login.php` and `register.php?country=xx` where xx varies and is always lower-case letters.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# Turn on ssl for specific pages
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^login\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^country=([a-z]+)$
RewriteRule ^register.php https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Turn off ssl when not accessing specific pages
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !\/register.php\?country=([a-z]+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !\/login.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirect non-canonical hostname requests, preserving http/https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}>s ^(443>(s)|[0-9]+>s)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%2://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not really need to check what `country=xx` is -- it's a query string parameter and is not important. Redirect to HTTPS should occur on per page basis, not per query string parameter.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# force https for /login.php and /register.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(login|register)\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# don't do anything for images/css/js (leave protocol as is)
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$ - [NC,L]

# force http for all other URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(login|register)\.php$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# your other rewrite rules below
```

1. These rules need to be placed in .htaccess in website root folder BEFORE any other rewrite rules (if such present). If placed elsewhere some small tweaking may be required.
2. They will

   - force HTTPS for `/login.php` and `/register.php`,
   - do nothing for images, css styles and JavaScript files (to be precise, for files with those extensions)
   - and will force HTTP for all other URLs
3. You can easily add other URLs to that list -- just edit existing rule by adding additional file name to the list (the same text in 2 places: 1) to force 2) to exclude)
4. File names are case-sensitive. So these rules will not work if `/LOGIN.php` is requested (Apache will not serve it either, as Linux is case-sensitive OS .. so no need to worry much here).
5. Obvious thing: mod_rewrite should be enabled and .htaccess files needs to be processed by Apache (some website hosting companies disabling them for performance and security reasons).

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**
It is very likely that these rule will not work for you straight away. That is because modern browser do CACHE 301 redirects from your previous attempts. Therefore I recommend testing it on another browser and change 301 to 302 during testing (302 is not cached) .. or clear all browser caches (maybe even history) and restart browser.

---

**BTW:**

1. No need to escape slash in `%{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !\/login.php$`
2. `%{SCRIPT_FILENAME}` will only match file name and definitely not the query string, therefore `!\/register.php\?country=([a-z]+)$` make no sense at all.

Comment: Thanks for replying. My register page is set up so that first the user must choose their country, while all other content is hidden, and after they make a selection, the sign up form is displayed. So I was trying to only secure the form... I give up though!, I'll settle for having the whole page secure. I tried your code, but something's not quite right. The turn off portion works, but when I try to go to the login or register pages, I get "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" (normally, I use Firefox, but am testing this with IE because of FF's stupid new persistent caching problem).

Comment: Ff tells me: "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

Comment: Also: I don't know if it makes a difference, but I'm testing on a subfolder of my home directory, which contains a copy of my entire site, to avoid causing errors on the live site while testing.

Comment: This code is taken from **fully working site**. 1) Try temporarily disabling ALL other rewrite/redirect rules you may have; 2) You may also have some redirect happening in your PHP code (since I do not know what your code is this is a possibility). So replace your current login.php and register.php by some very simple files, that only prints page name -- this will help identify where the problem may be; 3) Your server may be behind some proxy (behind nginx, for example) -- if so -- then rule will require modification depending on how proxy is set up to process SSL connections.

Comment: If it is inside some subfolder then yes -- it may affect the rewrite rules.

Comment: What got it to work for me was changing RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(login|register)\.php$ to RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !(login|register)\.php$   The rest of your code was perfect. Thanks!